# Getting a jquery lightbox to pull the image out of a <img> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website I am currently using a jquery plugin that scrolls images automatically across the page, which is all fine.

But if you click the image it just takes you to the image source and I want to use a lightbox feature incorporated with it. The problem is all the jquery lightbox codes I can find uses
a href tag to get the image url, but the scroller uses img as so;

img src="img/img1.jpg" longdesc="img/img1.jpg" width="400" alt="Image 1" /

how can I get around this?

Comment: What is wrong with `href`?

Comment: If I use h ref to enclose the img used by the other jquery scroller it stops working as I believe the jquery scroller is looking for media enclosed in a <img tag

Comment: Oh so this a problem because of nested jquery pluggins. Please post links to the pluggins you are using.

Comment: The image scoller covering most of my page is http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/ Image Flow. and the lightbox im trying use (happy to use an alternative is needed) if http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ Colourbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you are going to need to do is to disable the onclick behavior of Image flow: http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow/Documentation Luckily its available in the image flow options.

Something like `onClick : $.noop`

Next you need to make some alterations for your lightbox. Colorbox uses the `href` attribute to determine what content to display. Its not standard but you should be able to get away with an `href` attribute on an image element. Give it a shot.

```
<img src="img/img1.jpg" href="img/img1.jpg" width="400" alt="Image 1" />
```

Comment: just btw, I think your strategy is missing the point of lightboxes. The idea is you have a smaller low res image as a thumbnail, and a bigger high res image for the lightbox, that way the page loads faster. If its the same image for both, the lightbox does not have as much value.

Comment: Worked! think the main element i was overlooking is placing the 'class' in the <img also.. Thanks alot!! :)

Comment: It worked but the problem that because I have put a href inside img, I can not get my website to validate :(

Comment: yup its not valid. But I don't know if you have other options. Plus if it looks good and works cross browser, who's to complain?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the attribute of the img element by using "document.getElementById("id").src" or "document.getElementByTagName("img").src" in JavaScript and then assign that to a another tag the same way, just changing the "id" to the correct id and the "src" to whatever the attribute is.

Comment: Also using `jQuery` that would be `$('img').attr('src');`

Comment: So in this part of the js:"object", n ? "select" : "embed"].forEach(function(P) {
   Array.forEach(document.getElementsByTagName(P), function(Q) {